# Use conditional computed column in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables viz. #Exported_Data and User_Details.

**#Exported_Data:** (User_Id, User_Name, Status, Office_Id, Dept_Id, Service_Id, Allocation)

**User_Details:** (User_Id, Office_ID, Dept_Id, Service_Id, ServiceAllocation)

In #Exported_Data table, Status can be Inactive or Active.

In User_Details table, Allocation can be between 0 and 1.

User_Details table is a transaction table and #Exported_Data table is a temporary table which hold all records which need to be inserted into the Transaction table based on certain criteria.

I have a query:

```
insert into User_Details (User_Id, Office_ID, Dept_Id, Service_Id, ServiceAllocation)
select 
    User_Id, 
    Office_Id,
    Dept_Id,
    Service_Id,
    Allocation
from #Exported_Data ED
where not exists (select Office_ID, Dept_ID, Service_ID from User_Details UD where UD.User_Id = ED.User_Id)
```

In the above query, in place of Allocation, I have to insert an Allocation value based on certain conditions. The conditions are:

If Status of the user in #Exported_Data is Inactive then make Allocation 0, else

(1) Get Allocation of user from #Exported_Data

(2) Get sum(Allocation) of user from User_Details table

(3) If Allocation of (1) + sum(Allocation) < 1 then this Allocation value else skip insert

I tried using CASE statements but it is getting too complex to form the correct query. 
While inserting I am checking whether the combination (User_ID, Office_ID, Dept_Id, Service_ID) exists in the transaction table or not. The query should not insert duplicate row. It should only insert unique rows. For example, User 1 can be in two different departments or can have different Service Ids.

[image]

The Allocation value I want in query is:

Allocation value from #Exported_Data + sum(ServiceAllocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dun have full imagination of your act and your thinking.But you know RKH , If I were you I tried to bring **sum(ServiceAllocation)** into a variable in order to brief query.
also you are telling if **#Exported_Data.Allocation + sum(ServiceAllocation) >= 1** then skip insert, So you can put this into where clause to avoid fetching such these rows.
In my Idea you have to use either **case when statement** or **a function**.
But I suggest you this code below.May it be Useful.you can also declare a variable above your query(not in or as a function).
(personally,I dun like functions because it makes my query  two or sometimes three times lower specially in big queries )

```
Declare @Sum_ServiceAllocation as float
set @Sum_ServiceAllocation = (Select Sum(ServiceAllocation) from User_Details where User_Details.User_Id = (Select Top 1 User_Id from Exported_Data))
insert into User_Details (User_Id, Office_ID, Dept_Id, Service_Id, ServiceAllocation)
select 
    User_Id, 
    Office_Id,
    Dept_Id,
    Service_Id,
    (case Status when 'Inactive' then 0 else (ED.Allocation + @Sum_ServiceAllocation)end) as 'Allocation'
from #Exported_Data ED
where not exists (select Office_ID, Dept_ID, Service_ID from User_Details UD where UD.User_Id = ED.User_Id)
and (ED.Allocation + @Sum_ServiceAllocation)<1
```

Maybe It isn't all that close to your goal but it's just a suggestion

Comment: The sum(ServiceAllocation) is not for all users. It is for a particular user whose record is being inserted.

Comment: You have either User_Id as a parameter or in #Exported_Data Table.If you have it as parameter then you can use it directly.But if it's in #Exported_Data table ,There are two way.If #Exported_Data has several User_Id then you have to __join__ them if not then you can __Select Top 1 User_Id From #Exported_Data__. Which one?

Comment: I edited it supposing that you have just Unique User_Id in #Exported_Data per transaction